# How to (asynchronously) consume a steaming end-point generated with servant's StreamGenerators?

Tags: http, haskell, asynchronous, servant

The servant documentation describes how to create [streaming endpoints](http://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/Server.html#streaming-endpoints):

```
type StreamAPI = "userStream" :> StreamGet NewlineFraming JSON (StreamGenerator User)
streamAPI :: Proxy StreamAPI
streamAPI = Proxy

streamUsers :: StreamGenerator User
```

Now the question is how can a client (written in javascript for instance) consume the end-point in an asynchronous fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: that in newer `servant` (`0.15` IIRC) streaming was refactored. However, the question of how to consume *streaming endpoints* in JavaScript is irrelevant of backend implementation.

For example if you use *Fetch API*, you can use reader API, which is well explained in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams). Summarizing that:

```
// Fetch the original image
  fetch('./tortoise.png')
  // Retrieve its body as ReadableStream
  .then(response => {
    const reader = response.body.getReader();
```

Then you can call `reader.read()` to get response in parts.